# adding options to org-export dispatcher

Tags: org-export, latex

I'm trying to customize the workflow that goes from org-mode to latex export. When I launch the export dispatcher, I have four sub-options under [l]atex ... the standard ones. But I think it's possible to add more options, as you can see in this videoclip from an emacs meetup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzA2YODtgK4&t=2380s. Specifically, I'd like to use latexmk as my default exporter for org export to latex, and I can't figure out how to configure it.

What I really want is a way to launch latexmk directly as my exporter, so any way of doing that would be great.